# selecting records without value

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a problem when I'm trying to reach the desired result. The task looks simple — make a daily count of occurrences of the event for top countries.

The main table looks like this:

```
id |            date            | country |   col1   |   col2   | ...
1  |    2018-01-01 21:21:21     |    US   | value 1  | value 2  | ...
2  |    2018-01-01 22:32:54     |    UK   | value 1  | value 2  | ...
```

From this table, I want to get daily event counts by the country, which is achieved by

```
SELECT date::DATE AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', country, COALESCE(count(id),0) FROM tab1
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

The problem comes when there is no event was made by an UK user on 2 January 2018

```
country_events
   date    |  country | count
2018-01-01 |     US   |   23
2018-01-01 |     UK   |   5
2018-01-02 |     US   |   30
2018-01-02 |     UK   |   0  -> is desired result, but row is missing
```

I've tried to generate date series and series of countries which I'm looking for, then `CROSS JOIN` these two tables. This `helper` with columns `date` and `country` I've left joined with my result table like

```
SELECT * FROM helper h
LEFT JOIN country_events c ON c.date::DATE = h.date::DATE AND c.country = h.country
```

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an outer join, not a cross join:

```
SELECT tab1.date::date, tab1.country, coalesce(count(*), 0)
FROM generate_series(TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 00:00:00',
                     TIMESTAMP '2018-01-31 00:00:00',
                     INTERVAL '1 day') AS ts(d)
   LEFT JOIN tab1 ON tab1.date >= ts.d AND tab1.date < ts.d + INTERVAL '1 day'
GROUP BY tab1.date::date, tab1.country
ORDER BY tab1.date::date, tab1.country;
```

This will give the desired list for January 2018.

Comment: It's not working. Perhaps because when I make select from the tab1, there is no record date for this date, so row is not created like 
     date        |  country  | count
2018-01-01 |      UK     |   5
2018-01-03 |      UK     |   7

in this case, there is no way how to join tab1 select when there is no combination of 2018-01-01 with UK value... Isn't it?

Comment: Can you specify "it is not working"? Are there errors? Results different from what you described in your question? It might help if you add the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `tab1` to the question.

Comment: I'm sorry. There is no error but also no progress. Little progress was when I've changed `tab1.date` for `ts.d` but it can be caused by using `ON tab1.date = ts.d`. With this change, I've got the result like this
`2018-01-02 | NULL | 0` -> the `UK` country is missing. Is any approach how to achieve `2018-01-02 | UK | 0` without making `SELECT` for each country with `CASE WHEN country IS NULL THEN 'UK' ELSE country END ` and then union them all?

Comment: I don't understand. How was your `CREATE TABLE` statement?